# How to return 401 response in AWS API Gateway Lambda Authorizer?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using a custom Lambda Authorizer written in Python for an API Gateway Web Socket. How do I return a `401 Unauthorized` response from that?

[The documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) is fairly vague on it and only has a node.js example:

```js
exports.handler =  function(event, context, callback) {
    var token = event.authorizationToken;
    switch (token) {
        case 'allow':
            callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'deny':
            callback(null, generatePolicy('user', 'Deny', event.methodArn));
            break;
        case 'unauthorized':
            callback("Unauthorized");   // Return a 401 Unauthorized response
            break;
        default:
            callback("Error: Invalid token"); // Return a 500 Invalid token response
    }
};
```

Alternatively it allows to return an explicit Deny IAM policy:

> If the token value is 'deny', the authorizer function returns a 403 Forbidden HTTP response and a Deny IAM policy that looks like the following, and the method request fails:
>
> ```json
> {
>   "Version": "2012-10-17",
>   "Statement": [
>     {
>       "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
>       "Effect": "Deny",
>       "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456789012:ivdtdhp7b5/ESTestInvoke-stage/GET/"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

What if I want to respond with a `401 Unauthorized` though? What's the equivalent to `callback("Unauthorized")` in a Python Lambda handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is squirrelled away in [a comment](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/1e79ad02a4dcbbd0fe2951cf9a5de4aff7915823/blueprints/python/api-gateway-authorizer-python.py#L28) in a [sample repo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints):

```
"""you can send a 401 Unauthorized response to the client by failing like so:"""
"""raise Exception('Unauthorized')"""
```

You just need to raise a plain exception with exactly the string `'Unauthorized'`. Then the API Gateway will reject the connection with a nice `401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: [Same for NodeJS](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/1e79ad02a4dcbbd0fe2951cf9a5de4aff7915823/blueprints/nodejs/index.js#L26), thanks !